# Issue in STM32CubeMx

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32cubemx, smbus

While using STM32 CubeMX (version 5.2.1) and selecting the i2c in SMBus-two-wire-Interface it shows as follows:-

Warnings: STM32 CubeMX does not support the configuration of this mode of this IP.However,this IP can be configured manually.

Anyone please tell me the reason for this warning and also a solution for this